# WPF ListBox sliptted in 2 parts

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have to create a ListBox in WPF using template, which fill the entire form. 
But in the middle on the form (inside the ListBox), I have to display horizontally another ListBox, could some one help me:

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask. I suggest you post some sample code of what you already tried. Otherwise people will feel like you are expecting someone else to do your job and thus will be unwilling to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soemthing like this should work

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="anotherItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding anotherLabel}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding xpto}"/>
                <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource anotherItemTemplate}"></ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: then you have to explain better as @HighCore said.

Comment: Tell me your email and ill send you an email... ;)